# latin.lbx for biblatex

Tags: biblatex, languages

I started (a long time ago, but ...) to create a `latin.lbx` for `biblatex`, but there is one problem with some of the strings, and I'm hoping others have already tackled this for other languages.

The problem arises in strings like `bytranslator`.  Similar to Italian, you could have the following:

```
bytranslator = {{translatus \lbx@lfromlang\ a}{tran\adddot\ \lbx@sfromlang\ a}}, % though I think I favour 'interpretatus'
```

The problem is with the preposition 'a': if it's object begins with a vowel or 'h', the preposition should be 'ab'.  Is there a way to solve this at the `.lbx` level, or would it need to be done with something like a per-entry `options = {...}` field?

If we wanted to get more complicated, if the title is 'plural', as in

```
title = {Sancti {Augustini} confessionum libri {XIII}},
```

then the 'translatus' should be 'translati'.  However, this may be too rare a problem to matter since it is hard to imagine a Latin bibliography where there are books in *other* languages with titles like *Thirteen Books of Augustine's Confessions*, though I suppose anything is possible.

Comment: Please post a complete small example document to show the problem and allow testing of possible solutions,

Comment: `spanish.lbx` uses "smart" "and" strings. `french.lbx` and `catalan.lbx` have a smart "of". You need to pass bibliographic data to these smart commands. This is demonstrated in `biblatex.def`. If you're planning on contributing a module, the maintainers handle [this sort of stuff](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/biblatex/index.php?title=Adding_lbx_Files).

Comment: @Audrey -- Thanks, I'll take a look.  The link looks useful too.

Comment: @jon No problem. Again, contributors aren't expected to solve these issues on their own as we have to decide which features to incorporate. A smart "by" is worth considering. Not so sure about handling plural titles. Feel free to follow up with further Latin/Italian requirements at the biblatex github repo.