# Use Latin language with babel

Tags: babel, languages

I'd like to typeset some parts of the text in Latin language (preferably New Latin, if possible). Latin language is listed among supported languages of Babel. I invoke it as `\usepackage[main=british, french, german, latin]{babel}` and use in the text like `\begin{otherlanguage}{latin}TEXT\end{otherlanguage}`, but XeLaTeX keeps telling me `Language 'latin' not supported'.` This works well for the other languages I use. How can I use Latin language?

As comments suggest, the warning can be produced

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
bibstyle=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear-comp,
sorting=ynt,
autocite=inline,
maxbibnames=99,
mincitenames=1,
maxcitenames=2,
hyperref=true,
backref=true,
backrefstyle=none,
useprefix=true,
uniquelist=false
]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}}
```

I have some bibliographic entries written in Latin, but the bibliography is typeset in English.

I use texlive 2018.151 on openSUSE Linux. All Latin related packages (well, I have *all* packages installed) are installed.

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using and on what operating system?

Comment: Not sure what 2018.151 refers to, because of what's shown on [this page](https://software.opensuse.org/package/texlive?search_term=%22texlive%22). In the “vanilla” TeX Live, support of Latin is in `collections-langeuropean`.

Comment: I think this warning can be coming from another package, e. g. `biblatex`

Comment: @egreg It is version 2018, that 151 is package version (basically technical information). Shortly, it is the newest version with all updates. I have package `texlive-collection-langeuropean` installed
@MichaelFraiman If it is just warning from `biblatex` and everything works, might be I can just ignore it...?

Comment: Cannot say much more: apparently the support for Latin needs some “subpackage” to be installed.

Comment: I see. I'm very sure I have installed everything.

Comment: Is it “Tumbleweed” or “Leap”?

Comment: I'm almost certain this is not a `babel` warning. Judging by the quotation marks in the message and the wording itself I would bet quite a bit on `biblatex`. You can ignore the warning if you don't want to write your bibliography in Latin. BTW: [This is one of the prime examples why MWEs are so important on this site.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6255/35864) With an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that guess could be verified in an instant.

Comment: @egreg Tumbleweed, but IMHO it does not play any role here.

Comment: Just for future reference and sorry for pestering you: The code in the question is still not an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), the code in my answer would be an MWE. At least the question now mentions `biblatex` explicitly, but please consider making it a habit to include MWEs in your questions. See also the two links in my earlier comments.

Comment: If the bibliography is just to be typeset in british english, then consider passing `language=british` to `biblatex`.  However, that will not clear the warning message.

Comment: This omission is more important than in might seem, because (even though very few people write in Latin these days) many books are written in Latin, and, consequently, their titles are in Latin: so, bibliographies which refer to those titles should observe Latin linebreaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=british, french, german, latin]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem
\end{document}
```

produces the warning

```
Package biblatex Warning: Language 'latin' not supported.
(biblatex)                Using fallback language 'british' on input line 11.
```

Your editor may digest that message for you and may only display the 'important' `Language 'latin' not supported.` bit of that message prominently to you  robbing you of the chance to see that it comes from `biblatex`.

Due to the way language loading works in `biblatex`, all declared document languages are loaded at the beginning of the document even if they are not used at all. Languages that are not supported yield a warning. Since there is no `latin.lbx` Latin is not supported by `biblatex` (if you want to contribute a `.lbx` file for an unsupported language or know someone who can, drop by at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues). If you do not plan to typeset citations or the bibliography in an unsupported language you safely can ignore that message.

Comment: Apparently one TeX.SX wrote their private `latin.lbx` once, but that was sadly not released to the general public: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110951/35864

Comment: Indeed. I use [Kile](https://kile.sourceforge.io/) as the XeLaTeX editor and it did not show the second line of warning.