# macro creates latin on next line

Tags: line-breaking, babel

The below is in my header

```
\usepackage[latin, english]{babel}
\newcommand{\latin}[1]{\foreignlanguage{latin}{\emph{#1}}}
```

Example sentence:

```
when I use `\latin{ex nihilo}` in a sentence it breaks the Latin onto the next line.
```

**output:**
when I use
*ex nihilo* in a sentence it puts the Latin onto the next line.

However, if I use `\textit{ex nihilo}` instead, it outputs as I expect:

**output:**
when I use *ex nihilo* in a sentence it breaks the Latin onto the next line.

Can anyone tell me what is going on with my macro?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=1.7cm,bottom=1.3cm,left=1.9cm,right=1.9cm]{geometry}
\sloppy
\parindent=0cm
\hyphenation{}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\exhyphenpenalty=10000
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\usepackage[style=oscola,terseinits=true,ibidtracker=false,indexing=cite,citereset=chapter,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin, english]{babel}
\newcommand{\latin}[1]{\foreignlanguage{latin}{\emph{#1}}}
\begin{document}
This is a test example\latin{ex nihilo} to see what happens.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please complete the code to a fully compilable example document that reproduces the issue (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)? I just ran `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin, english]{babel}
\newcommand{\latin}[1]{\foreignlanguage{latin}{\emph{#1}}}

\begin{document}
when I use \latin{ex nihilo} in a sentence it breaks the latin onto the next line.
\end{document}` and I did not get an unexpected break before the *ex nihilo*.

Comment: I can't see it. Can you please add some more context? What TeX distribution are you using? In order to know it, just report the first ten lines of the `.log` file. I have tried the code with TeX Live from 2012 on and don't get the behavior you claim.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the replies. It appears its a biblatex issue in that it doesnt have a latin.lbx file - related to this post here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110951/latin-lbx-for-biblatex?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @PeteMcD and now you know why we ask for a full example, you never mentioned anything about `biblatex` in your question

Comment: Sorry, I am totally new to this. I have updated to show a MWE.

Comment: @jon, did you manage to ever find or create a latin.lbx file which can be used with Biblatex?

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce this with the following minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
  style=oscola,
]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

This is a test example\foreignlanguage{english}{ex nihilo} to see what happens.

\end{document}
```

If I comment out `style=oscola` (that, by the way, produces a few errors during the LaTeX run), the problem of `\foreignlanguage` being pushed on a new line disappears.

Solution: don't use `style=oscola`, which is buggy.

Some more information: compiling the example with TeX Live 2017 doesn't show the problem; compiling with TeX Live 2018 I get no error from `oscola`, but the problem shows anyway. With a current TeX Live 2019 I get also

```latex
! Package biblatex Error: Option 'url' already defined.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.135   \settoggle{bbx:url}{#1}}

? 

! Package biblatex Error: Option 'doi' already defined.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.137   \settoggle{bbx:doi}{#1}}

? 

! Package biblatex Error: Option 'eprint' already defined.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.139   \settoggle{bbx:eprint}{#1}}

?
```

---

Somehow, two blank lines and three unprotected endlines sneak in `\abx@extras@english`. They are caused by empty lines and missing `%` in `english-oscola.lbx`. Here's the diff with a fixed version.

```
109,110c109
<        \csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}}}}}
<
---
>        \csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}}}}}%
129,130c128
<        \printfield{extrayear}}}}}}
<
---
>        \printfield{extrayear}}}}}}%
145c143
<        \printfield{extrayear}}}}}}
---
>        \printfield{extrayear}}}}}}%
```

You should report the bug to the maintainers of `oscola`.

For the time being, you can patch the offending command.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}

\usepackage[
  style=oscola,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \patchcmd{\abx@extras@english}{ \par}{}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\abx@extras@english}{ \par}{}{}{}%
  \apptocmd{\abx@extras@english}{\relax\relax\relax}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\abx@extras@english}{ \relax\relax\relax}{}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Example\foreignlanguage{latin}{ex nihilo}

\end{document}
```

but I don't see how to fix the errors about the toggles in TeX Live 2019.

Comment: thanks for your comments @egreg - unfortunately not using oscola is not possible for me. It is the main use of LaTeX for me.

Comment: @PeteMcD I added a workaround until the maintainers of `oscola` fix the bug. I also showed how it should be fixed.

Comment: The option errors can be fixed as in https://github.com/PaulStanley/oscola-biblatex/pull/8

Comment: https://github.com/PaulStanley/oscola-biblatex/pull/10

Comment: @moewe Also `british-oscola.lbx` should be fixed

Comment: Yes, `american-oscola.lbx`, `british-oscola.lbx` and `english-oscola.lbx` all need to be fixed (their contents are virtually identical), but the pull request should do all that.